# Which distribution for percent composition data

Tags: r, distributions, beta-distribution, beta-regression, compositional-data

I want to test the effects of categorical enviromental parameters on the composition of sediments. I started to build a model using percent values of the (three) different compounds. However, I don't know which distribution I should use. For this kind of percent data I cannot use a binomial distribution since the percentages are not a result of bernoulli trials. I calculated the percentages using the weights of each compound. I also can't use the term "success,failure", i.e. cbind(weight_compoundA,total_weight-weight_compoundA), as response variable since these values are not integer but 5 digit continuous.
After some research I found that for this kind of data a beta distribution should be used. 
Since my data is nested and using mixed effects models with beta distribution seems very complicates in R: Any other recomendation?
What about arcsine squareroot transformation?
All values lay above 0 and below 1.

I also played with the betamix fuction from the betareg package but have difficulties estimating k.